# How we can generate Latitude/Longitude at the time of import while using Feed module

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using Feed Module For Importing Nodes Form CSV File. What i want that at the time of import how we can generate lat/long pair for every node imported. I have address in csv file for every node an i want to generate lat/long pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the location module in tandem with the location feeds module (http://drupal.org/project/location_feeds).  It can be configured to geocode the the addresses at the time of import.

I had to adjust some timeout settings as its possible to try to geocode addresses faster than the geocoding api allows.